# PyCharm PYTHONPATH with different parts of single logical package

Tags: python, configuration, ide, pycharm, pythonpath

Assume I have projects *deployment* and *cms* with this structure:

```
+ deployment
| + src
| | + my_company
| | | + __init__.py
| | | + deployment
| | | | + ...
+ cms
| + src
| | + my_company
| | | + __init__.py
| | | + cms
| | | | + ...
+ ...
```

My company has many projects that are distributed as single logical package `my_company`. This functionality ensures `extend_path` in each `my_company/__init__.py` file. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.extend_path

So then is possible import like this:

```
from mp_company import cms
from mp_company import deployment
```

Problem comes when I mark all `src` directories as **Sources Root** in PyCharm. Because then PyCharm sees just only one package (probably the first it encounters) for the first level of imports in suggestions box. So if I want sugesstions for phrase `import my_company.` it appears only `deployment`. Strange is that for second level of imports all working right. So all suggestions for phrase `import my_company.cms.` suddenly appears after I write dot character after cms package name.

Is there any option in settings to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23087.